# Determine if a given set of vectors span $\mathbb{R}[x]_{\leq2}$

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

I am working on a linear algebra question, which asks you to determine if  the vectors $(1+x), (1-x), x, (1+x^2)$ span the vector space $V=\mathbb{R}[x]_{\leq2}$.

I think that the four vectors do span the space; however, I am not sure exactly why I have this intuition.  Could you please suggest a logical way of thinking about this in a general case?  That is, if given a set of vectors, how could I more systematically determine whether they span $V$?

Answer (score 1):

You have the "canonical" basis $1,x,x^2$. So you should test whether those polynomials can be expressed in terms of linear combinations of your vectors. This is obviously the case here.

Answer (score 0):

Call them $P_1$, $P_2$, $P_3$ and $P_4$. We know $\{1,x,x^2\}$ span our vector space. If we can express them as linear combinations of the $P_i$ we are done.

$$1=\frac{P_1+P_2}{2}$$
$$x=\frac{P_1-P_2}{2}$$
$$x^2=P_4-1=P_4-\frac{P_1+P_2}{2}$$

The fact that $P_3$ is not used doesn't matter because if $\{P_1,P_2,P_4\}$ span our space means any augmented set spans the space

Answer (score 0):

Here is a systematic method.

If you know a basis of your space, you can determine the coordinates of the given vectors with respect to the basis. Let's call $\mathcal{B}=\{1,x,x^2\}$ the standard basis of your vector space and $C_{\mathcal{B}}$ the coordinate map:
$$
C_{\mathcal{B}}(1+x)=
\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\\0\end{bmatrix},\quad
C_{\mathcal{B}}(1-x)=
\begin{bmatrix}1\\-1\\0\end{bmatrix},\quad
C_{\mathcal{B}}(x)=
\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix},\quad
C_{\mathcal{B}}(1+x^2)=
\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Now, the dimension of the subspace generated by those four polynomials is the same as the rank of the matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & -1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
because linear combinations of the four vectors correspond to linear combinations of the columns of the computed matrix: the coordinate map is an isomorphism of vector spaces from $\mathbb{R}[x]_{\le2}$ onto $\mathbb{R}^{3}$.

It's immediate to see that the rank of the matrix is $3$; a row echelon form for it is
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & -2 & 1 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
that shows three pivots.

Answer (score 0):

The dimension of $V$ equals $3.$ Also,  the system of vectors $x,1+x, 1+x^2$ is linearly independent and generates a vector space of dimension $3$. Thus, it is a basis and $\langle x,1+x, 1+x^2\rangle=V.$  If we add  to a basis any non-zero vector then we get a  generating  set of the  vector space.  Therefore $\langle x,1+x, 1-x,1+x^2\rangle=V.$